# How to zoom attached images with any jQuery Zoom Plugin in WP?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I need help with my WordPress Theme. In my articles I use only attached images. So I made a product slider that automatic load images from attach to this product slider.
To display image I use:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($product_image->ID, array(350, 250)); ?>
```

But this function also create some div-elements in which the image is displayed. So I can't just add a needfull class to image as jQuery zoom plugin requires. Can anybody help me? I just want to use some of [these zoom plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-zoom-effects.html).

I don't have many reputation, so I can't post link on pastebin. 
Here is HTML+PHP

```
<div id="slides" class="grid_5">

<div class="slides_container grid_5">
    <?php 
    $product_images = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'order' => 'ASC'
            )
        );

    foreach($product_images as $product_image) :?>
        <div>


            <center>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($product_image->ID, array(350, 250)); ?>
            </center>
        </div>
    <?php 
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
<br>
    <ul class="pagination grid_5">      
        <?php 
        reset($product_images);
        foreach($product_images as $product_image) :?>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($product_image->ID, array(50, 50)); ?></a></li>
        <?php 
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
```

And generated HTML: http://pastebin.com/EZByPvYm

Comment: Link you have sent there are lot of them . Which specific zoom plugin are you using ? Also can you give us HTML code generated ?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_attachment_image()` has two more parameters, 4th parameter is for overriding the attributes of HTML tag which `wp_get_attachment_image()` generates, use below code.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($product_image->ID, array(350, 250), false, array('class' => 'YOUR-DESIRED-CLASSNAME')); ?>
```